# Handling errors/failures in ngrx/redux reducer functions

Tags: redux, ngrx, ngrx-effects

My question relates to redux and more specifically how to handle errors/failures from within reducer functions. I am in reference to the ngrx example app (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) and the way it handle errors/failures.

Here is the reducer function I am referring to:

```
export function reducer(state = initialState, action: collection.Actions): State {
  switch (action.type) {
    case collection.ActionTypes.LOAD: {
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        loading: true
      });
    }

    case collection.ActionTypes.LOAD_SUCCESS: {
      const books = action.payload;

      return {
        loaded: true,
        loading: false,
        ids: books.map(book => book.id)
      };
    }

    case collection.ActionTypes.ADD_BOOK_SUCCESS:
    case collection.ActionTypes.REMOVE_BOOK_FAIL: {
      const book = action.payload;

      if (state.ids.indexOf(book.id) > -1) {
        return state;
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ids: [ ...state.ids, book.id ]
      });
    }

    case collection.ActionTypes.REMOVE_BOOK_SUCCESS:
    case collection.ActionTypes.ADD_BOOK_FAIL: {
      const book = action.payload;

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        ids: state.ids.filter(id => id !== book.id)
      });
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Can someone please explain the necessity for dealing with those two actions from within the reducer function:

- `REMOVE_BOOK_FAIL`
- `ADD_BOOK_FAIL`

For instance why remove the book from the state (in the case of the `ADD_BOOK_FAIL` action)?

If the add book action has failed, then the book is not present in the store. Is it?

Comment: I'm not sure, but It could be because of api calls. When user add book, the book is added locally in the store, than book is sent to server, and when the server fails to save it to database (ADD_BOOK_FAIL) we need to delete it from store.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's the naming used that makes it a red herring, my guess is that ADD_BOOK_FAIL could be in use somewhere else for a different use case as a fall back mechanism.

I agree the way you describe it this doesnt make sense the developer did it for this reason.